# React Hook: only send data to server if the user stop typing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I want to build is an editor, which sync data between different clients. To not overload the server, I thought about a time window, that have to be passed without action to send data to server.

Currently my react state has a value editing. If editing switch from true to false, there will be send a patch request to server with new updates.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (store.bootstrapFinished && store.editing === false)
        saveLesson(store, dispatch, true)
}, [store.editing])
```

Editing is set to true, when the user starts typing (could be title change or text changes). To get the text sync with the server I want to set editing to false after a certain time the user do no changes, but useEffect only reacts to changes of specific value like in the code example above or on everyone.

But is there also a react function like useEffect witch is called everytime editing is depatched and not only on change? I read something about useRef but did not realy understand how to use it.

Comment: You need to pass an array of dependencies as second argument if you want to scope your effect to run only when certain properties changes. `useEffect(() =>{}, [props])`

Comment: Ok, yes I also thought about a counter to get a trigger, but there is no easier solution to delay a patch

Answer (score 0):

you should run the fetch function at the same moment you change that state

```
setEditing(true)
fetchOperation()
```

Comment: but than I have no delay between editing and fetch data!? In this why I will think every letter changed to the server

Comment: it will depend on how you handle the fetching asynchronous,
first setEditing(true)
then fetchOperation()
inside the callback or then or async/await, setEditing(false)

Comment: I need more information to understand this.The first function you write above dispatch the state with editing true, doesn't it? The second one sends the data to the server. Where is the delay? If I send data to server with (await fetch(...)) the only delay is the time, while the server needs to response or what did you mean with fetching asynchronous

Comment: is you use async/await there shoudn't be any trouble with async calls
setEditing(true)
await fetchOperation()
setEditing(false)

Comment: Editing is set while the use is typing not while the data are fetched to the server

Comment: sorry for the miss understanding. I rewrote the question, for clearify

Answer (score 0):

You can always pass the second argument in useEffect to let hook know on what value it should depend on.

```
useEffect(() =>{}, [])
```

By running an empty array [] as a second argument, you’re letting React know that your useEffect function doesn’t depend on any values from props or state.

Comment: but than it will be triggered on every change of the state, that means that the interval is also expanded if the user did not typ anymore

Comment: By passing empty array it will work as componentDidMount. You can specify the useEffect to only change when the certain prop or state changes by specifying that in the second argument.